# The functor Tor for $r_R$

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Suppose $R$ is commutative ring and $r \in R$. Show that if $r$ is a zero divisor, then $$\text{Tor}^R_n(R/(r),M) \cong \text{Tor}^R_{n-2}(r_R,M)$$ for $n\geq 3$, where $r_R =\{s \in R \ |\ rs =0 \}$.

I know that, when $r$ is not a zero divisor, $\text{Tor}^R_1(R/(r),M) \cong r_M$ and $\text{Tor}^R_n(R/(r),M) \cong 0$ for $n \geq 2$, but I'm not sure how to get a projective resolution for $r_M$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint.** Use the following exact sequence $0\to r_R\to R\stackrel{r\cdot}\to R\to R/(r)\to 0$ (by splitting it into two short exact sequences), and the long exact homology sequence for Tor.